# Click on the whole column in datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagridview

How I am going to select the whole row in datagrid? Even if I click just a one cell, it will select the whole column. Help me to figure it out. And also when clicking(double click) the whole column, it will go to the edit page. something like that. Thank you

Here is my xaml code..

```
<custom:RowNumber Header="#" Width="30" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewHyperlinkColumn Header="Url" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Url}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Price" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat=c2}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Can Be Bought" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CanBeBought, Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header=" Can Add To Wishlist" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CanBeAddedToWishList, Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Post your xaml code. On selecting cell, it will select row and not column.

Comment: @RohitVats there is the xaml code :)